# Android how to show images with Animation effect

Tags: android, animation

I have 2 images of different color balls. When I press the button I am changing the image on imagebutton from image1(ball1) to image2(ball2). What I want to do is show this image change(ie ball color change with a little animation, effect that it rotates and changes color.

Question: How can I get this effect of rotating ball image1 so that it becomes ball image2 ?
Question: I want to play some sound also along with this effect. How to go about it?

EDIT: basically what I want is: image1 revolves around(180 degree) and becomes image2.

Comment: basically what I want is: image1 revolves around(180 degree) and becomes image2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to rotate and hide image you will need to use a tween animation framework:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View. You need to construct animation set that will rotate and reduce alpha of the image.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="true" >
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="float"
        android:toDegrees="float"
        android:pivotX="float"
        android:pivotY="float" />
</set>
```

Then just use `ImageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.your_anim));`

This will allow you to fade and rotate the ImageView, while revealing another ImageView below the current one.

If you want to do transition inside of a single ImageView you need to use [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) which is a drawable that cross-fades one image to another. Unfortunately it won't allow you rotating content, so you either need to modify it, which is harder.

You could use [RotateDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable.html) as one of the drawables in TransitionDrawable, but I have never tried this.

Comment: Thanks EvilDuck.. Tween was indeed helpful. ;)